# Removing length 1 dimensions in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions, brackets

I'm a real beginner with Python, and I have a recurrent problem with my ndarrays.
I'm very confused with the brackets (is there any schematic synthesis of the use of brackets in Python anywhere?). I always end up having arrays with many dimensions.
Right now I have this one:

```
>>> values
Out[1]: 
array([[[ array([[ 4.23156519, -0.93539198],
       [ 3.50074853, -1.67043386],
       [ 4.64192393, -1.03918172],
       [ 4.52056725,  0.2561267 ],
       [ 3.36400016,  0.26435125],
       [ 3.82025672,  1.16503286]])]]], dtype=object)
```

From here, how can I reduce the dimensions? I just wanted a 6x2 array. I tried `np.reshape` but since the current shape of `values` is (1,1,1) I can't directly reshape the array in a 6x2 one.

I'm sorry for the silly question, I'm seeking a general and schematic answer that would explain me how to pass from a higher dimension to a lower one and vice versa.

Here is the way I created the `array`. `values` is `clustered_points`

```
indices=[] # initialize indices
clustered_points=[] # initialize array containing points in different sub-arrays=clusters
for k in range(len(mu)):
    a=r[:,k]
    index=[t for t in range(len(a)) if a[t] == 1]
    indices.append(index)
    clustered_points.append(data[indices[k]])
clustered_points=np.reshape(clustered_points,(len(clustered_points),1,1))
```

Comment: I can reshape this easily with `values.reshape(6,2)` ... what error do you get? Did you also try `values.astype(np.float).reshape(6,2)` ?

Comment: First case:
`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Second case:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Comment: You have an array within an array.  The outer one has dtype object.

Comment: How did you even come up with that code? Several of the length-1 dimensions you don't want, you're *explicitly adding* with that `reshape` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an array that matches your initial display, I have to take special care to embed one array within another:

```
In [402]: x=np.array([[ 4.23156519, -0.93539198],
       [ 3.50074853, -1.67043386],
       [ 4.64192393, -1.03918172],
       [ 4.52056725,  0.2561267 ],
       [ 3.36400016,  0.26435125],
       [ 3.82025672,  1.16503286]])
In [403]: a=array([[[None]]],dtype=object)
In [404]: a[0,0,0]=x
In [405]: a
Out[405]: 
array([[[ array([[ 4.23156519, -0.93539198],
       [ 3.50074853, -1.67043386],
       [ 4.64192393, -1.03918172],
       [ 4.52056725,  0.2561267 ],
       [ 3.36400016,  0.26435125],
       [ 3.82025672,  1.16503286]])]]], dtype=object)

In [406]: a.shape
Out[406]: (1, 1, 1)
In [407]: a[0,0,0].shape
Out[407]: (6, 2)
```

Simply doing a cut-n-paste from the display produces a different array with shape `(1,1,1,6,2)`.  That does not have the inner `array` marking.  Either way `a[0,0,0]` gives the inner `(6,2)` array.

`reshape` and `squeeze` work on a `(1,1,1,6,2)` array, but not on a `(6,2)` nested inside a `(1,1,1)`.  You need to understand the difference.

---

(edit)

To run your 'how I did it' clip, I have to make some guesses as to the inputs (that almost merits a downvote).

I'll guess at some inputs:

```
In [420]: mu=np.arange(3); r=np.ones((4,3));data=np.ones(5)
In [421]: %paste
indices=[] # initialize indices
clustered_points=[] # initialize array containing points in different sub-arrays=clusters
for k in range(len(mu)):
    a=r[:,k]
    index=[t for t in range(len(a)) if a[t] == 1]
    indices.append(index)
    clustered_points.append(data[indices[k]])

## -- End pasted text --
In [422]: clustered_points
Out[422]: 
[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]),
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

`cluster_points` is a list with several 1d arrays.

I can do

```
np.reshape(clustered_points,(12,1,1))
np.reshape(clustered_points,(3,4,1,1))
```

though it would be better, I think, to do `np.array(clustered_points)` first, and may be even check its shape.

Since

```
np.reshape(clustered_points,(len(clustered_points),1,1))
```

supposedly works then `clustered_points` must be a list of `n` single element arrays.  But this reshape should produce a `(n,1,1)` array, not your `(1,1,1,...)` array.

So that edit doesn't help.

=========================

> I'm seeking a general and schematic answer that would explain me how to pass from a higher dimension to a lower one and vice versa.

The first step is be clear, to yourself and others, what is the structure of your array.  That includes knowing `shape` and `dtype`.  And if the `dtype` is anything other than simple numerics, pay attention to the structure of the elements (e.g. objects within the array).

Singular dimensions (value 1) can be removed with indexing, `[0]`, or `squeeze`.  `reshape` also removes demensions (or adds them), but you have to pay attention to the total number of elements.  If the old shape had 12 elements, the new has to have 12 as well.  But reshape does not operate across `dtype` boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`numpy.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
a = [[[[[ 4.23156519, -0.93539198],
        [ 3.50074853, -1.67043386],
        [ 4.64192393, -1.03918172],
        [ 4.52056725,  0.2561267 ],
        [ 3.36400016,  0.26435125],
        [ 3.82025672,  1.16503286]]]]]
a = numpy.array(a)
print("a.shape=%s" % str(a.shape))
b = numpy.squeeze(a)
print("b.shape=%s" % str(b.shape))
```

gives

```
a.shape=(1, 1, 1, 6, 2)
b.shape=(6, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is probably, ***how did you create this array?***

A python `list` object cannot be manipulated in the same ways that `np.ndarray`s can be.  In general, once your final list is created, you can cast it into a numpy array:

```
values = []
# fill values with values.append(...)
# ...
values = np.asarray(values)
```

To find the shape of an array, you can use either `A.shape` or `np.shape(A)`.  To remove dimensions of length one, the best approach is to use the [`squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method either as `A.squeeze()` or `np.squeeze(A)`, i.e:

```
>>> values.squeeze()
array([[4.23156519, -0.93539198],
      [3.50074853, -1.67043386],
      [4.64192393, -1.03918172],
      [4.52056725, 0.2561267],
      [3.36400016, 0.26435125],
      [3.82025672, 1.16503286]], dtype=object)
```

If your `values` array is really what you've said, then it should also be fine to use `reshape`

```
>>> values.reshape(6,2)
array([[4.23156519, -0.93539198],
       [3.50074853, -1.67043386],
       [4.64192393, -1.03918172],
       [4.52056725, 0.2561267],
       [3.36400016, 0.26435125],
       [3.82025672, 1.16503286]], dtype=object)
```

If you're getting an error trying to `reshape` `values`, is it possible it is actually a `list` instead of an `array`?

Comment: It might as well be. I said `array` because that's what I read close to the variable on the Pycharm debugger.
I added the way I created the element in my question

Comment: @KillingBambi, No.  You're creating a `list`, which is not a `numpy` data structure, and behaves differently.  I've updated my answer.  Try recasting your `list` into an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 6x2 array then just do this:

```
A = array([[4.23156519, -0.93539198],
           [3.50074853, -1.67043386],
           [4.64192393, -1.03918172],
           [4.52056725, 0.2561267],
           [3.36400016, 0.26435125],
           [3.82025672, 1.16503286]], dtype=object)
```

If you want to reduce your array:

```
A = array([[[ array([[ 4.23156519, -0.93539198],
           [ 3.50074853, -1.67043386],
           [ 4.64192393, -1.03918172],
           [ 4.52056725,  0.2561267 ],
           [ 3.36400016,  0.26435125],
           [ 3.82025672,  1.16503286]])]]], dtype=object)
```

it is actually 1x1x1x6x2 array, you can get 6x2 by doing `A[0][0][0]`